# tidyverse issue with 4.2.1 update, what to do?

Tags: tidyverse, pacman

I am a beginner in R -
i just updated to 4.2.1. i kept getting the error below. ive tried uninstalling R and Rtools, reinstalled them both. also reinstalled all of my packages.
but i am still getting errors when i call up tidyverse.

when trying with:
[library(pacman)
pacman::p_load(dplyr, tidyverse, ggplot2, tidyr, knitr, here, lubridate,
Rcpp, googlesheets4, faraway, mosaic, av, plotly,
gifski, gganimate, png, janitor, skimr, swirl, ggbeeswarm,
spsurvey, ggpubr, broom, climwin, plyr, gridExtra,
reshape2, gapminder, magick, caret, plotmo, mgcv,gamclass,tidymv)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81JN4.png)

i get:

```r
[package ‘tidyverse’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\erin bell\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpgvKuST\downloaded_packages
tidyverse installed
Warning message:
In pacman::p_load(dplyr, tidyverse, ggplot2, tidyr, knitr, here,  :
  Failed to install/load:
tidyverse
```

> ][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayfV7.png)

when trying with just: `library(tidyverse)`,
i get:

```r
[> library(tidyverse)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 namespace ‘cli’ 3.1.0 is already loaded, but >= 3.3.0 is required
```

> ][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2i9kU.png)

thank you for any help.

Comment: try `p_update` which will update all your packages to current and compatible versions, then try to load again.

Comment: thanks - alas, it didnt work.
i get the same error as prior:

Comment: ...
tidyverse installed
Warning message:
In pacman::p_load(dplyr, tidyverse, ggplot2, tidyr, knitr, here,  :
  Failed to install/load:
tidyverse
>

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly (or not?) enough installing package `backports` fixed that for me.